# ajax form after 'submit' validation errors

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I have created a form using ajax and php. The initial load and entering values into the form are all working fine, but where I am getting errors, is after the submit button has been pressed. Here is the markup  for the form, and the ajax and php handlers:

relevant parts of form:

```
<form id="edit_time">

 <!-----form fields here----!>


<button class="saveRecurrence" type="button" onclick="editTimeDriver('.$_GET['driver_id'].')">Save</button>
```

ajax part:

```
function editTimeDriver(driver_id) {
var time = "";
if (driver_id)
{
time += "&driver_id="+driver_id;
}

var data = $("#edit_time").serialize();

$.ajax({
    url: "ajax.php?action=save_driver_event"+time,
    dataType: "json",
    type: "post",
    data: data,
    beforeSend: function()
    {

        $(".error, .success, .notice").remove();

    },
    success: function(json)
    {
        if (json["status"]=="success")
    {
        alert(json["message"]);

        $("#edit_time")[0].reset();

    }else{

        if(json["error"]["date_from"]){
        $("input[name=date_from]").after("<div class="error">"+json_time["error"]["date_from"]+"</div>");
        }

    }       
    }

});
```

}

This then passes to the php part which is:

```
$json = array();


 if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {

$date_from = tep_db_prepare_input($_POST['date_from']);


if (preg_match("/^([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})$/", $date_from)) {

$json['error']['date_from'] = 'Start Date is not valid!';
}



if (isset($json['error']) and !empty($json['error'])){

    $json['status'] = 'error';

    $json['message'] = 'Please check your error(s)!';

}else{

    $json['status'] = 'success';

    $json['message'] = 'Time Data has been successfully updated!';

}
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

Now for some reason, if the `date_from` field is left blank, and the form submitted, it doesn't come back with error message, instead it returns the success message. Can anyone tell me why it is not reading the errors?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code by this one

```
onclick="editTimeDriver('<php echo $_GET['driver_id'] ?>'); return false;"
```

The `return false` statement prevent the form to be submitted using http (as you want to send an ajax request)

And You where doing something weird with your `$_GET['driver_id']`

Don't forget that php is running server-side